# Postgresql @@ query with left join faced error

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I using textsearch-controls for fulltext search in postgres. And everything works correct. I created index and used in query. But when I have been needed join another table I faced with error.

```
> ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "p"
  LINE 10:             ON cp.product_id = p.id          
                                          ^
  HINT:  There is an entry for table "p", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

my query

```
SELECT 
    p.id AS id,
    p.sku As sku,
    cp .category_id,
    ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('english',name||' '||coalesce(description,'')||' '||coalesce(sku,'')||' '||coalesce(price,0)||' '||coalesce(category,'')||' '||coalesce(brand,'')), query) AS rank                        
FROM products p, to_tsquery('Urbanears:*') query
LEFT JOIN category_product cp 
        ON cp.product_id = p.id                                     
WHERE to_tsvector('english',name||' '||coalesce(description,'')||' '||coalesce(sku,'')||' '||coalesce(price,0)||' '||coalesce(category,'')||' '||coalesce(brand,'')) @@ query                                                                                   
ORDER BY rank DESC
```

without `left join` query with `@@ query` works correct without problem and without `@@ query` query with `left join` works correct. What I missed ? How to use `left join` with `to_tsquery` and `@@ query` ?

when I move left jpin after query I faced with another silent error

query

```
    SELECT 
p.id AS id,
p.sku As sku,
cp .category_id,
ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('english',name||' '||coalesce(description,'')||' '||coalesce(sku,'')||' '||coalesce(price,0)||' '||coalesce(category,'')||' '||coalesce(brand,'')), query) AS rank
FROM products p, to_tsquery('Urbanears:*') query
WHERE to_tsvector('english',name||' '||coalesce(description,'')||' '||coalesce(sku,'')||' '||coalesce(price,0)||' '||coalesce(category,'')||' '||coalesce(brand,'')) @@ query                                       
LEFT JOIN category_product cp 
ON cp.product_id = p.id

ORDER BY rank DESC
```

error:

```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "LEFT"
  LINE 11:           LEFT JOIN category_product cp 
                     ^

> Time: 0.001s
```

**UPDATE:**

```
SELECT 
b.category_id, a.id, a.rank

FROM (SELECT 
p.id AS id,
ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('english',name||' '||coalesce(description,'')||' '||coalesce(sku,'')||' '||coalesce(price,0)||' '||coalesce(category,'')||' '||coalesce(brand,'')), query) AS rank
FROM products p, to_tsquery('Urbanears:*') query
WHERE to_tsvector('english',name||' '||coalesce(description,'')||' '||coalesce(sku,'')||' '||coalesce(price,0)||' '||coalesce(category,'')||' '||coalesce(brand,'')) @@ query           

ORDER BY rank DESC) as a 


LEFT JOIN category_product b on b.product_id=a.id
WHERE b.category_id = 181
```

I did it when used subquery. Filter by full text search by some word and by category. But it is correct approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code

```
FROM X, Y LEFT JOIN Z ON ...
```

Is interpreted as

```
FROM X, (Y LEFT JOIN Z ON ...)
```

References to X are not valid inside the ON, because ON is only applying to Y and Z.

You shouldn't mix comma joins and explicit joins, make them both explicit like this:

```
FROM products p JOIN to_tsquery('Urbanears:*') query ON to_tsvector('english',name||' '||coalesce(description,'')||' '||coalesce(sku,'')||' '||coalesce(price,0)||' '||coalesce(category,'')||' '||coalesce(brand,'')) @@ query 
LEFT JOIN category_product cp ON cp.product_id = p.id
```